# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error when I run my application (MVC 3).  The project has a reference to Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.  I have both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 (both Express) installed.  I'm using 2012 with this application.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' could
>   not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +192    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +123
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11568160
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +485    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +79    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +337
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +280
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1167
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap' or one of its dependencies. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11700896
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +141    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +4869125

Answer (score 44):

If this is a part of a web application, you need to enable running 32-bit applications from application pool of IIS. This will solve your problem.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for reference: this answer is true ONLY because of the underlying 'BadImageFormatException' in the stack trace - there's lots of other ways you could get the headline error.

Comment: Some more help: 
Go to IIS > Application Pools > Select the relevant pool > Rigth click and select Advanced Setttings.. > Change "Enable 32bit Applications"

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll is probably not in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache), which means that it has to be copied in your web application's *bin* folder or manually added to your machine's GAC (e.g., using GACUTIL.exe). You can probably find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\`. If you referenced it from a location like that in your Visual Studio project, then you can probably just set the option in Properties of the reference for *Copy Local* to *True*.

Note that this DLL may not be redistributable, so you may have to actually install SSIS on any web server on which the application will run in order to not violate the SSIS licensing, but you will have to verify that.

Comment: Also for posterity: @schellack's comment here about licencing is spot on. The 'Runtime' DTS bits are installed if you install SSIS (server licence) or BIDS (client licence). So AFAIK there *is* a licencing implication either way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was solved after I enable the "Allow 32-bit Applications" on "DefaultAppPool" in the IIS.

Here are the steps to do that

1. Open Internet Information Services
2. Go to application pools
3. Right click “DefaultAppPool”
4. Select Advanced Settings
5. Set “Enable 32 Applications” to true
6. Click OK
7. Recycle the application pool
8. Restart the IIS

Answer (score 0):

In Application pool right click on DefaultAppPool .Then select advance settings.
[image]