# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer class in C# return error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am using following code to create an new db from existing ,the problem: it create new db from existing one but do not copy the objects and return error on line:"transfer.transferdata()" . the error is =

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

actually I have added this file to my project and the error still existed!!!

```
 public void con1(string oldfile,string newfile)
        {
            ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(".\\sqlexpress");

            Server server = new Server(conn);

            Database newdb = new Database(server, newfile);
            newdb.Create();

            Transfer transfer = new Transfer(server.Databases[oldfile]);
            transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
            transfer.CopyAllUsers = true;
            transfer.Options.WithDependencies = true;
            transfer.DestinationDatabase = newdb.Name;
            transfer.DestinationServer = server.Name;
            transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = true;
            transfer.CopySchema = true;
            transfer.CopyData = true;
            transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;
            transfer.TransferData();\\error on this line
        }
```

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified."...It states there is no such data or file..

Comment: @UpvoteMarkAnswer but I have it on my refrences !!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918142/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-dtsruntimewrap)

Comment: @beargle I have checked your link those solutions didn't worked for me !!

Comment: let me know if there is solution to copy database by transact sql?