# could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

Would like some help on this.

I am trying to execute an SSIS package programmatically (C#) through a console app as a work around. When debugging however I keep getting errors. I have tried using Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dlls (versions 11.0, 12.0 & 13.0) and Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap (32 & 64 bit) but still keep getting errors.

Don't know what else to do.

Comment: The 'Runtime' DTS bits are installed if you install SSIS (server licence) or BIDS (client licence). So AFAIK there is a licencing implication either way.

Comment: check out this answer and  comments :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918142/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-sqlserver-dtsruntimewrap

Comment: Thanks. SSIS (Data Tools) are installed on the server. I am currently using an evaluation license maybe that's the issue.